# Why is there a loss of energy when charge is redistributed among two objects?

Tags: special-relativity, electrostatics, charge

I am a high schooler so forgive me if I got anything wrong.

I had a question today stating that when charges are re-distributed among any two objects, there would be some loss of energy. The question focused on the cause of this "some loss of energy". I argued that this energy loss must be due to sparks and heat produced when the charge is transferred. One example is lightning, where the "objects" are the higher atmosphere and the ground. Due to the difference in the potential, lightning occurs where there is a large amount of heat, light, and sound is produced. But the answer was that "the change in mass due to the flow of charges was what caused the change in energy."

I have many questions. I assume we are using the formula $E=mc^2$, but even then, if we are considering a system of two objects, the mass is the same in the system, right? And thus, the energy loss due to mass difference should be $0$ / negligible, right? Secondly, isn't the equation $E=mc^2$ usually used when a nucleus is altered (fusion/fission)? Why would this be applicable when electrons are flowing (which it does when the charge is shared )? My best bet is that the answer stated is wrong and mine correct, but it would be unscientific if there were none to peer-review me.

---

The complete question is as follows.

> Assertion: When charges are shared between any two bodies, no charge
> is really lost, but some loss of energy does occur.
>
> Reason: Some energy disappears in the form of heat, sparking etc.
>
> Options
>
> a) Assertion and Reason are both correct, and Reason is the correct
> explanation of the Assertion
>
> b) Assertion and Reason are both correct, but Reason is not the
> correct explanation of the Assertion

Comment: Something seems off to me. The phrase "the change in mass due to the flow of charges" is not something I've ever encountered.

Comment: I think you're right and your teacher (or whoever set the problem) is wrong. In fact I find the answer provided to be nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an answer to this question based on two well-known phenomena. The first is the second law of thermodynamics, which states that with every energy transition, part of the energy is converted into thermal radiation. The second is the emission of photons from excited charges. Actually, the second penomenon is the reason for the first.

In short, whenever you try to manipulate the state of a system, some of the energy supplied is lost as radiation.